# Setting cookies for static files using bottle.py

Tags: python, cookies, bottle

New to python. I am using bottle.py as a web server.

I have a set of static HTML files that need to be rendered on different routes. I am using static_file() function for the same. I also want to set a session based cookie for the page. SO I am using response.set_cookie().

But it turns out that when I am returning a static_file the cookie is never set. However if I change the response to  a simple string, set_cookie() works fine. Can anyone explain why? And how can I fix this?

```
@app.route("/index")
def landingPage():
response.set_cookie("bigUId", "uid12345")
# return "Hello there"    
return static_file("/html/index.html", root=config.path_configs['webapp_path'])
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Welcome to Bottle and to Python. :)

Looking at the [Bottle source code](https://github.com/bottlepy/bottle/blob/master/bottle.py#L2459), the problem is readily apparent.  Look how `static_file` ends:

```
def static_file(...):
    ...
    return HTTPResponse(body, **headers)
```

`static_file` creates a *new* `HTTPResponse` object--so any headers you've set before then will be discarded.

A very simple way around this is to set the cookies *after* you call `static_file`, like this:

```
@app.route("/index")
def landingPage():
    resp = static_file("/html/index.html", root=config.path_configs["webapp_path"])
    resp.set_cookie("bigUId", "uid12345")
    return resp
```

I just tried it, and it works perfectly.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just tried, indeed it's not working, I never tried to use cookie with a static_file() before ... However, you can do the following to return a static file as a template, and the cookie will be set :

Your routing function :

```
@route('/test')
def cookie_test():
    response.set_cookie("test", "Yeah")
    return template('template/test.html')
```

And for this to work, you'll need to define a route for /template this way :

```
@route('/template/<filepath:path>')
def server_static(filepath):
    return static_file(filepath, root="./template")
```

(Obviously, change "/template" to whatever you need according to your project path !)

I'm doing it this way, and it's working fine ! I'm not sure why it doesn't work when you try to set a cookie with static_file(), it might come from the fact that IT IS a static file that you're serving, or whatever, I really don't know.

Also, using the template() function in order to server a "static" html page might not be the right way to do it, but I'm personnaly doing it since a while, and I've never had any issue with this.

Hope it helps !